# using std::accumulate, getting a "too many arguments" error

Tags: c++, accumulate

`std::accumulate` is supposed to be able to take either three or four arguments. In the former case it's just when you want to add the numbers in a container; in the latter case it's when you want to first apply a function and then add them. I've written code that generates a vector of random doubles and then does some stuff to them: first it performs an x->x^2 transform using `std::transform`, then adds them up with `std::accumulate`, and lastly combines the two actions into one using the four-argument version of `std::accumulate`.

Everything works except for step 3. Looking at the example code to be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/accumulate/, I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work, but I'm getting a "Too many arguments error" when compiling (I'm using XCode. For some reason it doesn't tell me the line number, but I've narrowed it down to the second usage of `std::accumulate`). Any insights?

```
#include <numeric>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

double square(double a) {
    return a*a;
}

void problem_2_1() {
    vector<double> original;

    //GENERATE RANDOM VALUES
    srand((int)time(NULL));//seed the rand function to time
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        double rand_val = (rand() % 100)/10.0;
        original.push_back(rand_val);
        cout << rand_val << endl;
    }

    //USING TRANSFORM        
    vector<double> squared;
    squared.resize(original.size());

    std::transform(original.begin(), original.end(), squared.begin(), square);

    for (int i=0; i<original.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << original[i] << '\t' << squared[i] << std::endl;
    }


    //USING ACCUMULATE
    double squaredLength = std::accumulate(squared.begin(), squared.end(), 0.0);
    double length = sqrt(squaredLength);
    cout << "Magnitude of the vector is: " << length << endl;

    //USING 4-VARIABLE ACCUMULATE
    double alt_squaredLength = std::accumulate(original.begin(), original.end(), 0.0, square);
    double alt_length = sqrt(alt_squaredLength);
    cout << "Magnitude of the vector is: " << alt_length << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The fourth argument to that [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) overload needs to be a **binary operator**. Currently you are using a unary one.

`std::accumulate` performs a binary operation between successive elements in a container, hence the need for a binary operator. The fourth argument *replaces* the default binary operation, addition. It does not apply a unary operation and then perform addition. If you want to square the elements and then add them, you would need something like

```
double addSquare(double a, double b)
{
  return a + b*b;
}
```

Then

```
double x = std::accumulate(original.begin(), original.end(), 0.0, addSquare);
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now (thanks to you!). Accumulate when called with a function pointer will start by passing the "init" value in as the first argument to the function, and the first element of the object as the second, and then subsequently will put the result of that calculation as the first argument, and the next element of the object as the second argument, and on and on.

Comment: My final complaint, as promised: Your binary operator is going to square the previous result and add it to the square of the new value to produce the running total.  That will quickly get out of hand, and I'm pretty sure is not what is intended.

Comment: Yeah my function is now
   `double binary_square(double a, double b) {`
   `    return a + b*b;`
   `}`
For the purposes of understanding I think it should be fine... and actually I don't think it would incur any significant memory/performance costs, or any obvious ones anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks again. I should have left the example out!

Comment: @limp_chimp yeah, I was in the process of fixing my example. I hope it didn't cause too much confusion.